# How can I remove the visible key from a query string using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, url-rewriting, query-string

I have been working on a web framework of my own for practice, similar to Rails, and I want to be able to achieve 'pretty' URLs like it has. I've been reading around the source---I've heard that it's possible to do this in pure Ruby. How is it possible to interpret a request sent from a user's browser, making something like `http://localhost:3000/users/Alonessix` into parameters sent to the sever as `http://localhost:3000/main.rb?route=/users/Alonessix`?

Comment: No, actually I haven't used it at all. I'm trying to do this from scratch because it's more of a learning experience for me than anything else. Let me guess, there's a way to do it with Rack?

Comment: Generally you'd use [Rack](http://rack.github.io) to hook your application up to a web server. Then Rack would give your app the `/users/Alonessix` path and your app could handle that path however it wanted. Without Rack, you just need a way to get the web server to give you the `/users/Alonessix` path and then you *route* it to the appropriate method in your app. You don't rewrite the URL, you internally map it to a method.